# CreatedAtAction throws InvalidOperationException when using API Versioning

Tags: asp.net-core

EDIT: [here's a repo](https://github.com/bruno-brant/dotnet-api-versioning-error) which simulates the error.

I'm building an API using ASP.NET Core together with [ApiVersioning](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning). My controllers are annotated with `[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion/[controller]` and on my POST actions I'm returning the location of the created resource:

```
return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), new { id = entity.Id }, entity);
```

When this line is ran I get an `InvalidOperationException` which the message:

> Message:
> Internal Server Error
> System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtActionResult.OnFormatting(ActionContext
> context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsyncCore(ActionContext
> context, ObjectResult result, Type objectType, Object value)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
> context, ObjectResult result)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext
> context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult
> result)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsyncTFilter,TFilterAsync
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed
> context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

If I remove the version tag from the URL pattern (thus becoming `api/v1/[controller]`) the error goes away. What am I missing?

Oh, here's how I'm bootstrapping my application:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddApiVersioning(o =>
        {
            o.ReportApiVersions = true;
        });

        // ... removed for clarity
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This scenario has been brought up a couple of times. Action parameters have a **BindingSource**. The **ApiVersion** is considered `BindingSource.Special` because it can come from multiple places. This behavior is similar to how the **CancellationToken** action parameter works. If memory serves me correctly, an action parameter must have `BindingSource.Path` to be considered in route URL generation, which makes sense.

The name of the action parameter that you add should not matter, but it *should* match what you've defined in your route template to be sensical. The member you add that's passed to **CreatedAtAction** or **CreatedAtRoute** **must** be the same as that defined your route template. The routing system wants to serialize the **ApiVersion** type into the route parameter, which is incorrect. To address that, you simply call `.ToString()`.

Putting that all together, this will work every time:

```cs
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{id}"]
    public IActionResult Get(int id) => Ok(new Model(){ Id = id });

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post(Model model, ApiVersion version)
    {
        model.Id = 42;
        var routeValues = new {id = model.id, version = version.ToString()};
        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), routeValues, model);
    }
}
```

The other way you can get the requested API version is to call `HttpContext.GetRequestedApiVersion()`. This method *can* return `null`, but in this context it will never be `null` by the time things have been routed to your action. This is ultimately just a shortcut extension method for:

```cs
var feature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IApiVersioningFeature>();
var raw = feature.RawRequestedApiVersion; // unparsed; e.g. exactly as requested
var version = feature.RequestedApiVersion; // parsed and validated
```

Answer (score 0):

It's solved, I'm leaving it here for future generations.

When calling `CreatedAtAction`, you must inform the `version` of the action you want to call. While this may be obvious, there's an exact way to do so:

Either capture the current version and pass it back:

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Post([FromBody] Pet pet, ApiVersion version)
        {
            if (pet.Id is null)
            {
                lock (_petStorage)
                {
                    if (_petStorage.Count == 0)
                    {
                        pet.Id = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pet.Id = _petStorage.Keys.Max() + 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            _petStorage.Add(pet.Id.Value, pet);

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetById), new { pet.Id, version = version.ToString() }, pet);
        }
```

Or define the desired version by creating an instance of `ApiVersion`:

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Post([FromBody] Pet pet)
        {
            if (pet.Id is null)
            {
                lock (_petStorage)
                {
                    if (_petStorage.Count == 0)
                    {
                        pet.Id = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pet.Id = _petStorage.Keys.Max() + 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            _petStorage.Add(pet.Id.Value, pet);

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), new { pet.Id, version = new ApiVersion(1, 0).ToString() }, pet);
        }
```

Comment: Passing in ApiVersion as a parameter is not by the book, neither is hard coding version inside controller method.

Comment: @RoarS. tell that to Chris Martinez, the creator of API Versioning: https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/654#issuecomment-672909417

Comment: @RoarS. also, if I can't either use a hardcoded version or a parameterized one, how do you suggest I pass the version to `CreatedAtAction`?

Comment: I'll moderate my self: I've seen some posts using ApiVersion as input parameter to controller method. So I guess this will be the appropriate way now. My apologize. If you remove the hardcoded version in your answer, I will reset my down vote.

Comment: Adding a `ApiVersion version` parameter will pass the current API version via _Model Binding_. You can also use the `HttpContext.GetRequestedApiVersion()` extension method. Both of these ultimately get the value from the **IApiVersioningFeature**, but you should never have to access that directly. You _can_ use a hardcoded API version, if and only if, your controller maps to exactly one version. That's a developer and implementation detail.